# Dell XPS 13 CPU Temps

Tags: dell-xps, thermal-paste, cpu-temperature

I have a 2019 Dell XPS13 7390 with 10th Gen Intel Core i7 CPU.

The original fan failed so I bought a replacement. The has the heatsink attached. The new unit had a square of what I believe to be grey thermal paste on the heatsink - protected by a hard plastic cover. I removed the cover and fitted the fan / heatsink.

The laptop runs ok but I'm a bit concerned about the CPU Temp.

I ran the Core Temp app and it reports all CPUs running about 70c when laptop is idling. They've each run at 100c when run at even moderate load.

Is this normal? Should I be applying my own thermal paste to the CPU before fitting the heatsink?

After re-fitting heatsink with new thermal paste:

[image: cputemp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met people that would argue that CPUs (especially GPUs) are designed to work at those temperatures, but I personally would feel better if I stayed far away from running that close to its thermal ceiling all the time. Those temperatures IMO are way too high. You should definite try to clean off the bottom of the heatsink and apply your own thermal paste.

Alternatively, I've bought coolers from places like ebay before that are mechanically compatible, but the quality suffers compared to the genuine part because they cheap out on the heat pipes or fins. Maybe there's a couple of screws you can remove on that fan so that you can keep your original heatsink and use it with the replacement fan?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I took your advice, removed the heatsink, cleaned old thermal paste (was pre-applied to new heatsink), applied new thermal paste. I've attached pic of core temps. As you can see, then still max out at 100cc but now hover around 50c under normal load - this seems to be cool enough for the fan to not even be started. If I run something more demanding then the fan starts and the temps rise to approx. 80c